# suggestBox: Suggestions aren't displayed as HTML anymore gwt 2.4 -->2.7

Tags: gwt, suggestbox

I am not familiar with *gwt* and I had to upgrade from *gwt* 2.4 to *gwt* 2.7.

I have a problem with a `suggestBox` item:
i need to interpret HTML tag present in the `MultiWordSuggestOracle`:

I overrided `isDisplayingStringHtml` to be sure it was set to true:

```
private MultiWordSuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle() {
    @Override
    public boolean isDisplayStringHTML() {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Then I tried to insert this :

```
 private void initOracle() {

    String gogogogo= "<tt>####</tt>";
    HTML html = new HTML("<tt>####2</tt>");

    List<String> listeSuggeree = new ArrayList<String>();
    listeSuggeree.add("<HTML><div>#####</div></HTML>");
    listeSuggeree.add((gogogogo));
    listeSuggeree.add(html.getHTML());
    listeSuggeree.add("AAAAAH nothing work");

    oracle.addAll(listeSuggeree);
    oracle.setDefaultSuggestionsFromText(listeSuggeree);
```

[HTML problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGTIT.png)

All worked perfectly on gwt 2.4 and I didn't find a way to interpret this HTML on *gwt* 2.7.0, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [MultiWordSuggestion](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MultiWordSuggestOracle.MultiWordSuggestion.html).

The constructor takes two parameters:

> **replacementString** - the string to enter into the SuggestBox's text box
> if the suggestion is chosen
>
> **displayString** - the display string

Basically, `displayString` is shown in the list, `replacementString` is shown in the TextBox after selection.

So, here is the proper way to prepare your suggestion list:

```
List<Suggestion> listeSuggeree = new ArrayList<Suggestion>();
listeSuggeree.add(new MultiWordSuggestOracle.MultiWordSuggestion("bold replacement", "<b>bold</b>"));
listeSuggeree.add(new MultiWordSuggestOracle.MultiWordSuggestion("italic replacement", "<i>italic</i>"));
listeSuggeree.add(new MultiWordSuggestOracle.MultiWordSuggestion("underline replacement", "<u>underline</u>"));
listeSuggeree.add(new MultiWordSuggestOracle.MultiWordSuggestion("SUCCESS!", "All works!"));

oracle.setDefaultSuggestions(listeSuggeree);
```

---

And the output is:

[image]

BTW: `isDisplayStringHTML` is `true` by default.

Comment: Thank you a lot, that work perfectly, you saved my day!